# Meta should also have the same votes separation feature as SO

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

When you click on the number of the votes on SO, the upvotes are separated from the downvotes, and you can see them.

Could you update meta with the same feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the same. You just need 1,000 rep on Meta to see them. You only have 450.

Comment: I've never understood why this feature has a minimum reputation.